# Passing Type to New Object Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a type that I created. something like this

```
type TrackMeta = {
   trackId: string;
   trackCover?: ImageMeta;
   trackLength: string
}[];

type ImageMeta = {
  mime: string;
  imageBuffer: Buffer;
  type: { id: number; name: string };
  description: string;
};
```

When I try to attach my type to an object I get "type not assignable to type TrackMeta[image]"

Comment: You declared `trackLength` as a `string`, but `tags.length` is probably a `number`.

Comment: so I tried both and I still got the same error. I thought that was the problem also

Comment: @Nellz are you sure that you will get `tags.length`  always as `number`? Probably your `tags` are null 

Use `trackLength: number | unknown`

Comment: Track meta is an array and you are trying to assign an object?